# how to clear all the items and add new item in the asp.net checkboxlist using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have one checkbox list like

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"  >
 <asp:listitem Value="1">Item 1</asp:listitem>
  <asp:listitem Value="2">Item 2</asp:listitem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>`.
```

I need to clear all the items such as Item 1 and Item 2 from checkboxlist and add the new value such as "Item 3" in the checkbox list using javascript. Can anyone k now the solution for that problem?

Thank you...

Comment: just curious since this is .NET why do you need java script..?

Comment: You can change it to Item 3 using JS, no problem but How can you work with it on server side if you change it with JS on client side? You will end up with a bad web app.. right?

Comment: You can't do that using JavaScript. Try Ajax tool kit controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record: `<asp:CheckBoxList ...>` is a server-side control. If you remove the items and add a new one using Javascript (client-side) and after that you do a post-back to the server, you'll lose everything that was done on the client side.

My advice is: do a post-back to the server and handle the items' remove and add operations using the `CheckBoxList` server-side standard events. It'll be much simpler!

Comment: Ok fine. Can you please tell me How to add cxheckboxlist items in javascript?

Comment: You still want to add items to the CheckBoxList using JavaScript? Don't you mean how to add items using the server-side events?

Answer (score 1):

The removing isn't a problem, but if you add new values and then perform a postback you'll start getting errors from ASP.NET.  If it sees information posted back from a static source (drop down list, check box list, radio button list, etc.) that wasn't one of the provided options sent then it assumes some malicious user is attempting to abuse the application and it freaks out (breaking the page).

If you don't want to do an entire page postback to perform this change then you can wrap the checkbox list in an UpdatePanel (along with whatever you need to trigger the changes to the list, if applicable) so that there isn't a full page postback just to change the items.  This will mean writing server side code to change the items in the list.